# How to create a virtual appliance in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, appliance

I'm brand new to the concept of virtualization and VMs and have downloaded VirtualBox and created my first VM (an Ubuntu box).

I understand that a "*virtual appliance*" is very similar to a VM, however it comes with a pre-configured software stack and may even include multiple virtual machines.  If this first assumption is not correct, please correct me!

My main question is this: in VirtualBox land, what is the difference between creating a virtual machine and a virtual appliance? Are they different file types? If I had two or three VMs, how would I go about turning them or packaging them into an appliance?

Comment: AFAIK, someone else created a VM, configured it, and provided the files for you to download and run it on your machine.

Comment: So if an "appliance" spanned multiple VMs, it would not manifest itself as a single file (e.g., "`multi-vm-widget.appliance`"), but you would have to launch several VMs separately (different files) and make sure they were all working with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None.  A Virtual Appliance IS a prebuilt and configured Virtual Machine.  It's a convenient way to deliver a application stack to a customer that will work without much setup.